Bot response to embedding
In Vertex AI I can ground my process with either Google Search which gives me links to websites if I ask for them or with my own data stores of various kinds.
What I want to achieve is that I first want to get a search-grounded response --> store said websites for later reference in a vector DB in GCP and then query that later by another bot.
I want to build a service that for instance gets me stock market news, and stores that whole article in a vector db, which I can call a second time a few weeks later. I do not want to use the grounded search every time as it is expensive.
Due to the confusing terminology on Google's side and the documentation not being the greatest I am stuck.
